# Representation of $m$-th division field extension of an elliptic curve as composite field extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve with CM from an imaginary quadratic field $K$. Let $K(E[m])$ denote $m$-th division field (number field obtained by adjoining the coordinates of the $m$-torsion points of $E$. Then if $m=p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_k^{r_k}$, can we say that $K(E[m])/K\cong K(E[p_1^{r_1}])\cdots K(E[p_k^{r_k}])/K$, where $p_i$, $i=1,2,\cdots,k$ are prime numbers? And, on a related note, can we say that $Gal(K(E[m])/K)\cong Gal(K(E[p_1^{r_1}])\cdots K(E[p_k^{r_k}])/K)$?

Comment: The addition law is defined over $\Bbb{Q}$ so yes if $E(L)$ contains $E[a]$ and $E[b]$ then it contains $E[lcm(a,b)]$.

Comment: @reuns would you be kind enough to provide explicit proof for this since my intuition for the statements is based exactly on what you have mentioned but I am unable to sketch the proofs in a proper mathematical way?

Comment: Which step is unclear to you? The second question about Galois groups is much harder.

Comment: Yeah, I am not able to formulate the proof for the Galois groups. Maybe if you can provide some hints then at least I will have something to begin with?

Comment: The Galois group part is about investigating the kernel of $Cl(\Bbb{Z}[pn\tau])\to Cl(\Bbb{Z}[n\tau])$

Comment: @reuns what is $Cl$, $p,n,\tau$ here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140561/discussion-between-anish-ray-and-reuns).